# Flutter iOS Local notification - is it possible to notify only once?

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification, awesome-notifications

I'd like to notify user only once, no matter how many local notifications are going to be send with the same ID. I'm using [awesome_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) package. Also tried [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

Imagine the scenario that I'd like to display downloading progress, updating notification content e.g. each second. It's easily achievable on Android using following configuration with `onlyAlertOnce`

```
final NotificationChannel channel = NotificationChannel(
      channelKey: 'basic_channel',
      channelName: 'channel_name',
      channelGroupKey: 'channel_group_key',
      channelDescription: 'channel_description',
      onlyAlertOnce: true,
    )
```

However, the same channel configuration on iOS keeps sending alert&badge&sound each time I create notification with the same ID.

Is similar behavior achievable on iOS, that User will see updated notification content in Notification Center, but without being alerted?